# Create a transform stream out of a ChildProcess

Tags: node.js, stream, child-process

Is there a (simple) way to obtain a transform stream from child process that was executed via `spawn`, where the `Readable`/`Writable` sides would correspond to the `stdin`/`stdout` of the child process? For example, this would enable me to do something like this

```
stream.pipeline(
    createReadable(),
    childProcessToTransformStream(child),
    createWritable(),
    callback
);
```

My current solution is to `stream.pipeline` twice: one instance to pipe `createReadable()` to `child.stdin` and a second instance to pipe `child.stdout` to `createWritable()`. But I don't like this solution because it does not compose well: If there was a function like the hypothetical `childProcessToTransformStream` above, it would be possible to create more complex pipelines, such as:

```
stream.pipeline(
    createReadable(),
    childProcessToTransformStream(child1),
    childProcessToTransformStream(child2),
    createWritable(),
    callback
);
```